# (FreeBSD) When 3000 or 4000 people suddenly start logging in at the same moment, the port in the same seconds is not responding.

Tags: tcp, udp, kernel, port, freebsd

I manage a game server through FreeBSD 11.0 - 64 Bit.

I have a problem with this. When 3000 or 4000 people suddenly start logging in at the same moment, the port in the same seconds is not responding. But there is no such thing as closing. No error. He just keeps taking it slowly.

I have ipfw.rules, but I keep the limit scrs at the highest value.

What should I do?

Comment: Do I need to make a setting related to the kernel?

Comment: You should be celebrating having that many users. Time to look into distributed computing and load balancing.

Comment: @EJP My problems: sonewconn: pcb 0xfffff8000dfc3740: Listen queue overflow: 193 already in queue awaiting acceptance (28 occurrences)

Comment: Your game server code isn't accepting the connections fast enough. Profile it and figure out why. (For example, maybe don't just call `accept` once per loop, but keep calling it until it returns `EWOULDBLOCK`.)

Answer (score 2):

I recommend a look at [tuning(7)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=tuning). Several [sysctl](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sysctl) tunables are available to affect networking.

I think this one is your best bet:

> ```
>  The kern.ipc.somaxconn sysctl limits the size of the listen queue for
>  accepting new TCP connections.  The default value of 128 is typically too
>  low for robust handling of   new connections in a heavily loaded web server
>  environment.  For such environments, we recommend increasing this value
>  to   1024 or higher.
> ```

This one is probably not yours, because it affects per connection performance, but I would still try to go up and down with the value, just to be safe:

> ```
>  The net.inet.tcp.sendspace   and net.inet.tcp.recvspace sysctls are of par-
>  ticular interest if you are running network intensive applications.…
> ```

I would try turning this one off:

> ```
>  The net.inet.tcp.always_keepalive sysctl determines whether or not   the
>  TCP implementation   should attempt to detect dead TCP connections by
>  intermittently delivering ``keepalives'' on the connection.  By default,
>  this is enabled for all applications; by setting this sysctl to 0,   only
>  applications that specifically request keepalives will use   them.
> ```

Of course the usual rules of tuning apply:

- Don't use a tuning setting unless you understand what it does.
- Change one setting at a time, measure the effect.

Good luck.